# The "Create a company alert" on job description page is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

This is to report a bug on SO Jobs.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open a job description page (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/287543/frontend-developer-global-scale-solutions-gmbh);
2. Scroll down and click the "Create a company alert".

**Expected result:** 
A new alert is created and a confirmation message is displayed.

**Actual result:**
Nothing happens.

**Additional information**

The link has `_blank` target:

```html
<a class="js-alert-trigger fs-body2" data-context="JobDetail" target="_blank">Create a company alert</a>
```

Checked on several random jobs.

Comment: Yeah, known issue. Sorry. It almost certainly worked, but the notification is hidden behind the sticky top bar. You can try creating the alert and then immediately scrolling up, then you'll see the toast notification in the top right corner. We have an outstanding bug for this and I just bumped it up in priority.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? I'm unable to reproduce the error on Chrome, but I'd like to cover our bases before I mark this and non-repro.

Comment: @Juice, I believe this has been fixed already. I've just checked it in Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) for MacOS and the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, but I'll take Max's word that it was. We must have accidentally fixed it at some point.